# Xampp page is accessible by network from everyone with security enabled

Tags: linux, xampp

I have installed lampp server on Linux Mint on my desktop and I have run the script to secure the lampp server with success.
Everything is fine and I can access my sites from the home network specifically from my laptop using Windows 7 using http://192.168.1.2/site.

However I can also access the lampp pages http://192.168.1.2/xampp from my laptop although I should't. It should ask me for the login details.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what the problem was.
In /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp-conf file I had put Require all granted instead of Allow from all.

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```